# AVD Freezes after sometime

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio as my IDE for development. And i created a virtual device that was a preset for Nexus 5. Here are the details for the AVD,

[image: AVD Details]

So when i build my app for the first time and ran it using the emulator, it got frozen at the lock screen. By that time i wasn't looking at any logs. Then i ran it again and then it was successfull. But i let it be for some time (approx. 10 mins), and when i checked again the AVD was frozen. Then i saw the **logcat** logger was writing in an endless loop the following error,

> 02-02 17:48:32.768    1233-1259/system_process E/libsuspend﹕ Error writing to /sys/power/state: No such device

It just keeps on writing. And the ADB logs had the following,

> PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline

Why is this happening? Is it some kind of a configuration issue?

Comment: Linux user ? if yes then open terminal and ..sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya nope windows

Comment: open task manager & stop adb.exe (end process)

Comment: I can kill the process... It's not the issue.. i have to keep on restarting the AVD when i develop with this issue..@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: I've got the same problem i'm getting the PropertyFetcher error after launching AVD. We have the same setup (Nexus 5 - API 21). It's becoming frustrating because i have to restart the AVD everytime i run my app. There's no definite solution anywhere. I'm on the verge of givng up.

Comment: @myk I resolved the problem somehow, and i can't remember how i did it. So gimme sometime while i try to recreate the scenario and give you solution if i can :)

Answer (score 7):

Try locking and unlocking your emulator by clicking F7. ( Check the logcat updates when you do this)